# Pre-selected drop down not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The drop down appears empty when i am using this code, how can i fix this please?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2" >


  <select ng-model="singleSelect" class="form-control" required>
             <option value="2">All</option>
             <option value="1" selected="singleSelect == '1'">Male</option>
             <option value="0">Disapproved</option>
     </select>                  
</div>
```

Comment: init `$scope.singleSelect = '1'` in controller, or use `ng-init="singleSelect='1'"` in view. but it's better in controller

Answer (score 2):

You should use **ng-selected**    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-2" >
     <select ng-model="singleSelect" class="form-control" required>
             <option value="2">All</option>
             <option value="1" ng-selected="(singleSelect == 1)">Male</option>
             <option value="0" ng-selected="(singleSelect == 0)">Disapproved</option>
     </select>        
</div>
</div>
```

Angular.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.singleSelect = 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7a4pzkuq/

Comment: why added this `ng-selected="(singleSelect == 1,0)"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2" >
     <select ng-model="singleSelect" ng-init="singleSelect = 1" class="form-control" required>
             <option value="2">All</option>
             <option value="1" >Male</option>
             <option value="0">Disapproved</option>
     </select>                  
</div>
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <select ng-model="FormData.DefaultOption" class="form-control" ng-options="option.Name for option in FormData.MyOptions track by option.Value" required></select>
</div>
```

add the following to your controller outside the functions:

```
    $scope.FormData = {
    DefaultOption: { Name: 'Male', Value: 1 },
    MyOptions: [{ Name: 'All', Value: 2 }, { Name: 'Male', Value: 1 }, { Name: 'Disapproved', Value: 0 }]
};
```

A much cleaner approach. When using it use the value you need from the object